# How can I make sure that python finds the necessary data files?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, python-module, setup.py

Please consider this script:

```
$ tree my_application 
my_application
├── my_application
│   ├── sound.mp3
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_application.py
│   ├── my_application.pyc
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│       └── my_application.cpython-34.pyc
├── my_application.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── entry_points.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── run.py
├── MANIFEST.in
└── setup.py
```

`my_application.py` is a script that just plays `sound.mp3` using `mplayer`:

```
class Sound():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmd = ["mplayer", "sound.mp3"]            
    def play(self):
        subprocess.Popen(self.cmd)
```

`setup.py` is your classical setup.py file, with a `console_script` to `my_application:main`.

`MANIFEST.in` contains a reference to `sound.mp3` to make sure it gets copied when running `setup.py`:

```
include my_application/sound.mp3
global-exclude *.pyc
```

`run.py` contains a small piece of code to run the `main()` function of `my_application`:

```
from my_application import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There's an `__init__.py` file too, so that the `main()` function is correctly shown to the 'outside world':

```
from .my_application import main

__all__ = ["main"]
```

Now, this script works when I run the `main()` function while being in the inner `my_application` directory. But as soon as the function is run from somewhere else, e.g. by running `run.py` or using the console script, `mplayer` complains that it can't find `sound.mp3`:

```
Cannot open file 'sound.mp3': No such file or directory
```

How can I make sure that `mplayer` finds `sound.mp3`, no matter the directory I'm in?

Comment: Can you show the piece of code that is loading the `sound.mp3` file?

Comment: Have you used a relative path to `sound.mp3` that is valid from within a script that is in a different directory? The error you're describing sounds an awful lot like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346800/python-file-does-not-exist-error/28346955#28346955) here.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone: Sure. Updated. OliverW: See the update. I think I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using setuptools, you can use [`pkg_resources`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#resource-extraction) to retrieve the correct path to the file:

```
import pkg_resources

class Sound():
    def __init__(self):
        sound_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(
            'my_application', 'sound.mp3')
        self.cmd = ['mplayer', sound_path]

    ...
```